# Quality: Custom AVFoundation Camera App VS. iOS standard Camera App

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation

I have performed a number of tests using various subjects and lighting. Each test shows the standard iOS Camera App quality as being significantly superior (colors not washed out, better focus, better lighting, less grainy) to my custom AVFoundation based App. I cannot account for the *huge* differences. Below is an example screen capture from a video taken with both methods (using front camera).

iOS Standard Camera App
[image]

Custom AVFoundation Recorded Video
[image]

Code for custom implementation:

```
let chosenCameraType = AVCaptureDevicePosition.Front

//get camera
let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
for device in devices
{
    if (!device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo))
    {
        continue
    }

    if (device.position != chosenCameraType)
    {
        continue
    }

    camera = (device as? AVCaptureDevice)!
}

do
{
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh      

    let video = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
    captureSession!.addInput(video)

    let audio = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)) as AVCaptureDeviceInput
    captureSession!.addInput(audio)

    fileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    captureSession?.addOutput(fileOutput)

    captureSession!.startRunning()

    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString

    let name = String(UInt64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000))
    fileOutput?.startRecordingToOutputFileURL(NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "\(documentsPath)/" + name + ".mov"), recordingDelegate: self)
}
catch let error as NSError
{
    print(error)
}
```

Please try! You will see the difference, too...

Comment: Have all your tests been in low level or artificial lighting? You probably need to enable 'lowLightBoost'. There is a property on AVCaptureDevice,  automaticallyEnablesLowLightBoostWhenAvailable. That could make up the difference you're seeing.

Comment: yes, that test was done in low light. i tried enabling that property you suggested, but it said it wasn't supported when tested with the front facing camera. the pictures i posted primary show a lighting issue, but other tests I have done show more issues (especially when i tested my portrait). The default camera app looked spectacular (not washed out, appropriate lighting, less grainy, sharp, etc.) compared to my test using AVFoundation which looked like it was done with a 5 cent CMOS sensor.

Comment: Did you try the other low-light boost app methods? Have you compared your results to those of Apple's AVCam-iOS sample code?

Comment: I don't think that your tests are somehow valid, AVFoundation has a plenty of options to recreate camera app qualities. For instance, you do not set AVCaptureDeviceFormat, neither exposure or focus. You are barely using defaults. So your results highly depends on your code implementation, I'm sorry to say that is pretty plain. To do a better test try to download this https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/AVCamManual/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: What is your session preset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed what you are describing and looking at your code I don't see you implementing:

```
backCamera.focusPointOfInterest = focusPoint
backCamera.focusMode = AVCaptureFocusMode.autoFocus
backCamera.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureMode.autoExpose
```

I implemented this inside `touchesBegan` so that the camera would focus on the area where the user touched the screen. Here is that section of code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touchPoint = touches.first
        let x = (touchPoint?.location(in: self.view).x)! / self.view.bounds.width
        let y = (touchPoint?.location(in: self.view).y)! / self.view.bounds.height

        let realX = (touchPoint?.location(in: self.view).x)!
        let realY = (touchPoint?.location(in: self.view).y)!

        let focusPoint = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)

        let k = DrawSquare(frame: CGRect(
            origin: CGPoint(x: realX - 75, y: realY - 75),
            size: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150)))


        if backCamera != nil {
            do {
                try backCamera.lockForConfiguration()
                self.previewView.addSubview(k)
            }
            catch {
                print("Can't lock back camera for configuration")
            }
            if backCamera.isFocusPointOfInterestSupported {
                backCamera.focusPointOfInterest = focusPoint
            }
            if backCamera.isFocusModeSupported(AVCaptureDevice.FocusMode.autoFocus) {
                backCamera.focusMode = AVCaptureDevice.FocusMode.autoFocus
            }
            if backCamera.isExposureModeSupported(AVCaptureDevice.ExposureMode.autoExpose) {
                backCamera.exposureMode = AVCaptureDevice.ExposureMode.autoExpose
            }
            backCamera.unlockForConfiguration()

        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(500)) {
            k.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

When the camera is displaying the dark image the user can simply tap the screen and it will adjust the exposure and focus which brightens up the picture.